# Merge columns into row by one colunm value

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I merge rows by one columns value?
Suppose, we've got df:

```
variable  value
x1        a
x2        a
x1        b
x2        b
```

And I need data frame like this:

```
variable  value1  value2
x1        a       b
x2        a       b
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you figure out why it didn't work? Please edit the question to add more information (i.e., code) that helps us better understand where you need help.

Comment: `reshape` is the searched topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfN)[, ind:= paste0("Value", 1:.N), variable]
dcast(dfN, variable~ind, value.var='value')
#  variable Value1 Value2
#1:       x1      a      b
#2:       x2      a      b
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dfN %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    mutate(ind= row_number()) %>%
    spread(ind, value)
```

Comment: I'll do that in two minutes)